# Not able to present view controller from framework iOS

Tags: ios, frameworks

I have made a framework in which one view controller and associated xib exist, but there is one problem I am unable to access this file from another project in which this framework is imported, please suggest the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some changes in your framework

In xcode click on the Target and go to the “Build Phase” section, add the public H files to “public” in the “Headers” build phase:[image]

Comment: Also make sure you add your public header to the umbrella header.